# Looking for the current list of supported channels for the Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: botframework

I am looking for a link to the current list of supported channels for the Microsoft Bot Framework.  Anyone have that?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the documentation topic: "[Connect a bot to channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/portal-configure-channels)".